# How to prevent pending network requests from blocking further network requests?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker

I am developing a client that consumes GeoServer and ArcGIS Server endpoints. Essentially it's a search interface that allows for toggling map layers. On toggle, a map layer is requested. Requesting a map layer results in around 50 networks requests for all the different image tiles.

When all the servers are operational, I'm finding that is fine. However if one server is not responding then the results from all other servers are delayed to the point that it looks like the UI is not responsive.

i.e. If I request 'layer 1', that will queue 50 network requests. Browsers only execute a few requests at a time (6 I think for Chrome?). Therefore if I toggle 2 additional layers, that queues 50 x 2 requests = 100 requests. If the second layer is also from a map server that is down, then the result is the user having to wait for 100 requests to time out before 'layer 3' is added.

Having written this out... I guess that the solution is to offload requests to a webworker or a service worker? If I use a service worker, can I get the requests to individual images to cache? An example of such a request is:

```
https://api.atlas.saeon.ac.za/proxy/csir/RCP45_B_AveTemp_v3/MapServer/export?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=256%2C256&BBOX=22.5%2C-33.75%2C33.75%2C-22.5&BBOXSR=4326&IMAGESR=4326&DPI=90
```

Comment: Not sure WebWorkers can bypass this limit, and not even sure for ServiceWorkers... How long does a normal request generally take? You should be able to set a client-side timeout to your requests ([XHR.timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) or [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) for `fetch`). And if you always fetch from the same sets of servers, maybe you can filter out the ones that did timeout.

Comment: Setting the timeout would probably solve it. I'm not sure I have access to that in some of the network requests though. will have to check. (I'm using OpenLayers WMS helper)

Comment: You should also think about prioritizing the requests (use queue, set short timeout, handle long last) and managing the resolution. Go you really need 50 tiny images to assemble single map? If I divided my screen into 50 sections, single section would be 200x200 pixels. And that's the entire screen, browser view is smaller. I can see `SIZE` parameter in the URL you shared.

Comment: Ah thanks. it never occurred to me that I could specify the size. that will help. how can i know which requests will take the longest?